# Is there anything positive about Stanley in A Streetcar Named Desire?

Tags: character-analysis, a-streetcar-named-desire, tennessee-williams

Is there anything positive about the character of Stanley in the play *A Streetcar Named Desire*? I vaguely remembered that he supported Blanche to meet with that man... Is there anything more about Stanley that is positive? If yes then please help me to point out what it is in the play... Thank you.